# Javascript Create audio tag from array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of musics like that:

```
var files=["song1.mp3","song2.mp3","song3.mp3", "song4.mp3"]
```

And I want to display all on audio tag, I've done this but it doesn't work.

```
for (var in files){
$("body").append($("<audio> <source src="+"/audio/" + element" type='audio/mpeg'></audio>"));}
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: `var in files` should be `element in files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example your loop is incorrect. To loop over arrays you can use one of the following methods:

1. for loop using array length: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

   `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { /* array[i] is your item */ }`
2. Array.forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

   `array.forEach(function(item) { /* item is your item */ }`
3. for of loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

   `for (item of array) { /* item is your item */ }`

Note, that you will have to check the supported browsers for the last two methods.

Comment: Thank you but i don't know why it doesn't work.
You can see my code here: https://codepen.io/PiR1/pen/wePPvB

Comment: Well, it would work, if your would actually import the library you are using (jQuery) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop, you don't need to include a variable declaration.
Your loop should look like this:

```
for(element in files)
{
   $("body").append($("<audio> <source src='/audio/" + element + "' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>"));
}
```

Note I have added an extra + sign and changed the brackets order and type for the src tag.